# ASP.NET reCaptcha CustomTranslations Inline Syntax

Tags: asp.net, json, dictionary, recaptcha

What is the inline syntax we should use for Dictionary property?

`<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recap" CustomTranslations="string, string" Runat="server"/>`

I know this can be achieved programmatically but I hope not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of struggling, I am using deserialization approach via Json .NET framework to customize reCaptcha.

using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[Category("Appearance")]
[DefaultValue(null)]
public string CustomTranslations
{
            `get { return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize((object)this.customTranslations); }

            set { this.customTranslations = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(String.Concat("{", value, "}")); }`
}